# How to setup a 24 hour data lookup c#

Tags: c#, datetime

I am working on a chart that will plot the data points from 6 a.m. to 6 a.m. the next then repeat for the next day. The chart will plot from 6 am say today to 6 am tomorrow reset then start plotting for tomorrow's data.

Here is my variables

```
`DateTime startDateTime = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day, 6, 0, 0);
DateTime EndDateTime = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day, 23, 59, 59); ( no good need it for next day at 6 am)
```

` How can I make my enddatetime variable for tomorrow at 6 am?

Comment: What's wrong with `endDateTime = startDateTime.AddDays(1)`?  DateTime methods: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime_methods%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood it correctly then it is as simple as:

```
DateTime startDateTime = DateTime.Today.AddHours(6); //DateTime.Today set to 6:00 AM
DateTime endDateTime = startDateTime.AddDays(1);
```

`DateTime.Today` will give you the current Date with time part set to `00:00:00`, you can add `6` hours to it and that would give you current Date set to `6:00 AM`. To get `endDateTime` you can add `1` day to your `startDateTime`.

If you want your `endDateTime` to be Current Day + 1 and time set to `5:59:59` then you can do:

```
DateTime endDateTime = startDateTime.AddDays(1).AddTicks(-1); //(most  accurate)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 endDateTime = startDateTime.AddHours(24);
```